# Swift iOS DateFormatter for Japanase Calendar

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad, dateformatter

I'm extracting a date from a zip file, if the calendar is Japanese, it extract this string:

> [R 2/03/13 19:00:17]

that is 13-mar-2020 19:00:17

I found on iOS documentation that  `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")`is printing:

```
// Japanese Locale (ja_JP)
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
print(dateFormatter.string(from: date)) // 2001/01/02
```

By searching on internet, I think the "R" is meaning Reiwa Era.

Do exist a dateFormat that could give the year?

Something like:

```
let stringJap = "[R 2/03/13 19:00:17]"
let stringJapDate = stringJap.replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "")
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ja_JP")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "? y-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // the "?" means if is existing a character to describe Era in Japanase
let date = dateFormatter.date(from:stringJapDate)!
```

I'd avoid to build a switch case to extract the year by following the table below.

I found on internet this Era conversion:

2019 - Present ~ Reiwa Era
Western Calendar    Japanese Calendar   Western Calendar    Japanese Calendar
2020    Reiwa 2 2019    Reiwa 1 / Heisei 31

```
1989 - 2019 ~ Heisei Era
Western Calendar    Japanese Calendar   Western Calendar    Japanese Calendar
2019    Reiwa 1 / Heisei 31      
2018    Heisei 30   2003    Heisei 15
2017    Heisei 29   2002    Heisei 14
2016    Heisei 28   2001    Heisei 13
2015    Heisei 27   2000    Heisei 12
2014    Heisei 26   1999    Heisei 11
2013    Heisei 25   1998    Heisei 10
2012    Heisei 24   1997    Heisei 9
2011    Heisei 23   1996    Heisei 8
2010    Heisei 22   1995    Heisei 7
2009    Heisei 21   1994    Heisei 6
2008    Heisei 20   1993    Heisei 5
2007    Heisei 19   1992    Heisei 4
2006    Heisei 18   1991    Heisei 3
2005    Heisei 17   1990    Heisei 2
2004    Heisei 16   1989    Heisei 1 / Showa 64
```

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: From http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns use G for the Era.

Comment: You should also probably set the `dateFormatter.calendar` to `Calendar(identifier: .japanese)`.

Comment: And your date format doesn't have "/" like in the string, but "-", why? It doesn't match at all, no?

Comment: Try `let dateFormatter = DateFormatter();  dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .japanese); dateFormatter.dateFormat = "GGGGG y/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"; let date = dateFormatter.date(from:stringJapDate)!`

Comment: You should also change your locale to "en_US_POSIX" when working with fixed date format

Comment: No need to remove the brackets from your string `"[GGGGG y/MM/dd HH:mm:ss]"`

Comment: @Larme grat, your solution works! many thanks!

Comment: @SimonePistecchia don't forget to set your locale to "en_USPOSIX". It should be set before setting your dateFormat. If you don't set your date formatter locale to it your dateFormat will reflect the user device's locale and settings. If the user changes the time to 12h format it might crash your app. BTW don't force unwrap the result

Comment: I won't answer, because I made quick assumptions on the format, not sure it really works and that's the good date. Maybe some Japanese developer could enlight us. I was going to escape the `]` char in the format with simple quotes, no need? I'll test.

Comment: @Larme your format is correct. You just missed the locale for fixed date format. BTW No need to escape the brackets